# Is it possible to perform a "LIKE" statement in a SSIS Expression?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-like, case-statement, dataflowtask

I'm using a Derived Column Task to change column data using a CASE WHEN statement. However, I need to be able to say..

**SQL CODE WOULD BE:**

```
CASE WHEN Column01 LIKE '%i%' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
```

**In SSIS Expression Language that would be:**

```
[Column01] == "i" ? "0" : "1"  (that's for equals i, not, LIKE %i%.
```

Is it possible to use a LIKE operator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you'll want to [use the FINDSTRING function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx).

> FINDSTRING(character_expression, searchstring, occurrence)
>
> ...
>
> FINDSTRING returns null if either character_expression or searchstring
>   are null.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to write this using what you gave me, hopefully the results will be correct. ISNULL([Column]) ? "1" : ! ISNULL(FINDSTRING([Column],"I",1)) ? "0" : "1"  - If column 1 is null, then 1.. THEN if column 1 has an I in there it will return a value, therefore not null, so it will then show a 0, else 1.

Answer (score 30):

I know it is an old question, but these days I found a good answer on web.

If you want a expression for **Contains** `like '%value%'` you could use :

```
FINDSTRING(col, "value", 1) > 0`
```

If you want a expression for **Start with** `like 'value%'` you could use :

```
FINDSTRING(col, "value", 1) == 1
```

And finally, if you want a expression for **End with** `like '%value'` you could use :

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(col), X))  == "value"
```

More details look this useful resource : [Basic SSIS Equivalents to T-SQL's LIKE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/toddmcdermid/2012/05/22/basic-ssis-equivalents-to-t-sqls-like/)