# SSIS Conditional Split - check if a string has a substring

Tags: string, ssis, substring, conditional-statements

I am wondering if there is a function in SSIS Conditional Split, that would tell me if the string in my datacell has a substring "XYZ" or not. The condition would look like this:

CheckIfValueContainsSubstring("XYZ")

Unfortunately I can't find such function. Is there any way of achieving the goal of separating the record which have the substring from the records which don't have it?

An important note: the substring can be anywhere (so the typical substring function doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct expression for this in SSIS is FINDSTRING.

```
FINDSTRING( «character_expression», «string», «occurrence» )
```

[MSDNArticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx)

[Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739230/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-like-statement-in-a-ssis-expression)