# Using SSIS Parameters in LIKE Query

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis

I'm not able to find the right syntax to use a parameter within a LIKE clause in an SSIS SQL Server OLEDB Source component. For a trivial example, consider the following single-column table "tblTeams", listing teams and team members as a single string (it's stupid, I know):

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ TeamMembers   ║
╠═══════════════╣
║ A - Joe       ║
║ A - Melissa   ║
║ B - Frank     ║
║ C - Angela    ║
║ A - Luis      ║
║ C - Ashley    ║
║ B - Sam       ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

I want to run a for loop that exports files of members per team. The loop has an input variable from an array of team names: "A", "B", "C", etc. I'd like to use that variable as a parameter in an OLE DB Source to select the team members as such:

```
SELECT  [TeamMembers]
FROM    tblTeams
WHERE   [TeamMembers] LIKE '?%';  --where ? is param = "A", "B", or "C"
```

However, the syntax here considers the parameter placeholder to be question mark string. Moving the placeholder outside breaks the LIKE clause. Is it possible to use an SSIS parameter in a LIKE?

Comment: you will have to use findstring function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739230/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-like-statement-in-a-ssis-expression

Comment: try 
SELECT  [TeamMembers] FROM    tblTeams WHERE   [TeamMembers]like  ? + '%'

Comment: @ChintuS FINDSTRING is not directly applicable here because I am writing a SQL Query, not an expression. A good suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: @sandeeprawat I did not expect your solution to work because of the single quote placement, but it does! If you repost as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use ? and map it to string data type .

IE
       SELECT [TeamMembers] FROM tblTeams WHERE [TeamMembers]like  **?** + '%'

As ? is automatically converted in proper data format.

Answer (score 2):

Create variable *SQL_Select* type String, and define an Expression `"SELECT [TeamMembers] FROM tblTeams WHERE [TeamMembers] LIKE '" + [User::TeamMemberName] + "%'"` on this variable. Here I assumed you used a variable *TeamMemberName* type String with aforementioned param A, B or C.
Then on OLE DB Source component - set *SQL command from variable* ad Data access mode and select *User::SQL_Select* in a variable name drop-down.