# ssis case statement derived column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

still learning about SSIS

I have an excel source in SSIS, I need to create a case statement based on one of the columns `[Teacher]`

but as a derived column (as it does not work in the SQL statement)

the normal SQL would be

```
CASE WHEN [Teacher] like '%A%' then [Teacher] else null end as [Teacher]
```

I have tried to look for examples, but can't find any with use of the like '%A%'

please help

Comment: Since you're learning, what were some of the search terms you were using?

Comment: search google, it's actually better than searching stackoverflow for stackoverflow results: ssis derived column using like. First result is exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739230/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-like-statement-in-a-ssis-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) with [FINDSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function as following *(assuming that `[Teacher]` column is of type `DT_WSTR`)*:

```
FINDSTRING([Teacher],"A",1) > 0 ? [Teacher] : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

Comment: Thanks for this , but how do I amend for the opposite to bring back the values in same column , but not wanting the ones that have "A"  I have tried FINDSTRING([Teacher],"A",1) < 0 ? [Teacher] : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)  and FINDSTRING([Teacher],"A",1) =1 ? [Teacher] : NULL(DT_WSTR,50). with no joy. please help

Comment: @Joeysonic use `= 0`

Comment: thank you its ==0 .. fab. last issue I have its case sensitive I have one record that's ...a...instead of A ...I have tried the following FINDSTRING([Teacher],"A",1) + FINDSTRING([Teacher],"a",1)  > 0 ? [Teacher] : NULL(DT_WSTR,50), but record still there, how can I please amend

Comment: It was unexpected to find one record with a small 'a', but have to filter them out some how , please help x

Comment: Try using `FINDSTRING(UPPER([Teacher]) ,"A",1)`